# Error in Spring : Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]

Tags: spring

I'm getting this error in spring mvc framework :
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]

any advice ?

Comment: Post your configuration-xml to analyze further. Ensure you have declared the schemaLocations in the XML.

Comment: Are you running your application on Jetty?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have put the correct version of schema in your xml.
Also make sure that the same version jar file is included in your application.

If you are using SpringSourceToolSuit or have Spring plugin installed in your eclipse then you should be able to create the Spring configuration file with having correct schema defination in it by default.